# Tracing a closure

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to trace a closure in CL? For ex., can I trace foo-3 below?

```
(defun foo (n)
    (lambda (i) (incf n i)))
FOO
(setf foo-3 (foo 3))
#<CLOSURE :LAMBDA (I) (INCF N I)>

(funcall foo-3 2)
5
(funcall foo-3 2)
7
(trace ???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do so. Trace looks for functions in the function-namespace, so make sure to not mix values and functions.

```
(setf (symbol-function 'test)
   (let ((n 0))
    (lambda (x)
     (incf n x))))
=>
#<Interpreted Closure TEST>
(trace test) 
... 
(test 4)
=>
 0[2]: (TEST 4)
 0[2]: returned 4
4
(test 3)
=>
0[2]: (TEST 3)
0[2]: returned 7
7
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been going over http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#Symbol-Components, http://www.dreamsongs.com/Separation.html and the CLTL. I am getting a good feel for this now. Any other resources on this topic of namespaces that are worth referring to?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible: as far as I know, the trace macro generally works by replacing the function at a given symbol by a wrapper that calls the original and also prints out the tracing bit.

If you're interested in the (complicated) implementation details, the SBCL code is in [src/code/ntrace.lisp](http://repo.or.cz/w/sbcl.git/blob/HEAD:/src/code/ntrace.lisp) (you probably want to look at the trace-1 function).

Of course, if all you want to do is print something out when foo-3 is called, you could always put a print statement inside the lambda form in foo...

Comment: Is there something fundamental about closures that makes writing a trace function for them impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `trace` requires a function name, rather than there being a problem with tracing closures. Continuing from your example above, you can call `foo-3` from a named function, and trace that:

```
(defun call-foo-3 (i)
   (funcall foo-3 i))
(trace call-foo-3)
(call-foo-3 2)
  0: (CALL-FOO-3 2)
  0: CALL-FOO-3 returned 15
```